# Cypher query problem when trying to find max of a returned column under certain relation id

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am facing a very strange problem I am calling the same function `get_objects()` `4` times and getting the `max` from the returned column, the item `10172` which should be returned as a maximum still present in the result list but instead of that it returns me another item `9998` which is not a maximum. While for other two calls to the same function with another parameter it gives me correct results.

I have run and tested the statement into Neo4j browser, it gives me the same problem behaves like just that node doesn't exist, but when I individually search for that node `10172` which should be returned as a maximum it does exist in the database but why it is not returning me as maximum in final result?

I also extracted the CSV file from the Neo4j to double check the relation and presence of that specific node. It exists. Where I am going wrong?

I have a data stored in a graph database as `4` types of nodes and they are connected with different `4` relations and the relation `id` attribute as `(1,2,3,4)` In cypher query I am trying to get the maximum `paper id` against relation `1`. The problem seems to be exists with relation `1` and relation `4` calls. But I rechecked into database these nodes are present under these particular relations.

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
def get_objects(x): 
    par = str(x)
    query = ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) WHERE r.id = $par RETURN a.id '''
    resultNodes = session.run(query, par = par)
    df = DataFrame(resultNodes)

return df[0]

def find_max_1():
    authors,terms,venues,papers=0,0,0,0
    authors=get_objects(1).max()
    terms=get_objects(2).max()
    venues=get_objects(3).max()
    papers=get_objects(4).max()
    return authors,terms,venues,papers

def main():
    
    m = find_max_1()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        
        main()
```

The output is:

```
[9998, 14669, 10190, 9999]
```

Expected output:

```
[10172, 14669, 10190, 15648]
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was returned result was string type and `max()` was calculating maximum between `strings` instead of `int`.